# How to mock/bypass external dependencies and workflows in Flutter Integration test?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

I'm writing a Flutter app which only has a Google Sign In based on [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) and [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in). I'm unable to find a standard working example of how to mock the dependencies in Flutter or how to click the Google Authentication Dialog or bypass the whole authentication workflow.

I'm using `flutter_driver`  for writing Integration test as mentioned here.

[image: Google_Sign_In]

app_test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:pruoo_app/main.dart' as app;

void main() {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();
  app.main();
}
```

login.dart

```
//...imports

class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginViewState createState() => _LoginViewState();
}

class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  StreamSubscription<AuthenticationState> x;

  void getStream(AuthenticationState state, BuildContext context) async {
    if (state.toString() == 'AuthenticationAuthenticated') {
      print("Navigate to Main Page");
      );
  }
}

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthenticationBloc authenticationBloc =
        BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context);

    x = authenticationBloc.state.listen((state) {
      getStream(state, context);
    });

    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: GoogleSignInButton(
          onPressed: () {
            authenticationBloc.dispatch(LoggedIn());
          },
        )));
  }
}
```

Comment: A related Flutter issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15245